# How do I take out this pin from an axle connector?

Tags: technic, disassembly

I have an axle connector with a blue pin stuck in it. How do I get it out?

It looks like this:

[image]

It's on very tightly. I tried removing it for 5 or so minutes, but it's too slippery.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I usually attach it to a Technic beam, then put something to fill the hole so it can't squeeze together and come out, to give a handle.

The flexible rods tend to be a nice options for filling the hole, the older ones may be a bit better, but I've had success with other pieces that fit minifig hands.

[image: example]

Once you have the blue pin attached to the beam instead of that red piece, you can take the rod out and push it out with an axle or something if needed.

Comment: You can additionally put a short (3-4 stud) axle in the red piece to get a better grip on it.

Comment: It's a pretty good idea, but it doesn't work :(. The problem is probably that the axle pin is too tight on the red piece. EDIT: It worked just didn't use enough force the first time...

Comment: This is such a great technique.  Have *often* encountered this, and have always hated using my defualt modus operandi: my teeth. :)

Comment: BTW, another piece instead of the flexible rod that works really well (just tried it) is the [*Pin 1/2 w/ 2L Bar Extension*](http://img.bricklink.com/ItemImage/PL/61184.png)

Answer (score 0):

The [Brick Separator](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/Brick-Separator-630) can be used to apply a force between blue and red pieces (use the sharp end)

Comment: I have that tool; can you elaborate on how it would work in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a monkey wrench, but the connector will be a little bit squeezed.